# WPF XML update and treeview Update(UI)

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, treeview

I'm binding treeview with the following code, so update xml file and reload treeview. Xml file  correct return and TreeViewItem correct return but There is old data on UI. UI not changed.

Xaml:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="193" Cursor="Hand"                              
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" Margin="0,27,0,0">
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Name="MenuItemNew" Header="Yeni"  Click="OpenWindow" ></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
    </TreeView>
```

C# :

```
 public void TreeviewBinding()
    {
        try
        {
            TreeGroup.Items.Clear();
            TreeGroup.Items.Add(FillTreeView(Tools.LoadXml()));
            TreeGroup.Items.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This return XElemet :

```
Tools.LoadXml()
```

This XElement that fill TreeViewItem and return it:

```
FillTreeView(Tools.LoadXml());
```

After xml update called TreeviewBinding() method.

Comment: Try to add the line: TreeGroup.InvalidateVisual(); after TreeGroup.Items.Refresh();

Comment: Thank you, result is the same

Comment: You're not binding anything... I would use a `XmlDataProvider` instead.